# Generate CSR using BlackBerry RIM api

Tags: blackberry, csr

I want to generate CSR using RIM api, I search a lot in google but not even got a single one.
Can any one have any idea related to the same

Thanks

Comment: @PeterStrange, if you hover your mouse over the `csr` tag applied below the question, it gives you a description of that tag (keyword).  In this case, it's a Certificate Signing Request.  Of course, sometimes, users do apply tags incorrectly, but I'm guessing this is what he/she means in this case.

Comment: yes that is right tag..

Comment: OK, never used one myself.  When I search on Google I find a few hits including this one: http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/BlackBerry-Device-software/Certificate-Signing-Request/td-p/551574